# VBscript/SQL concatenation of %

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript

Ok, I am new to the forum and fairly new to coding, I've searched high and low, and I understand that vbscript requires escapes or Chr() to use special characters. In the following code I need to concatenate a '%' after the "doc_no" as a wildcard for a sybase database to pull up the list of document numbers that I need to appear in my table.
I have tried

```
' " & doc_no " ' & Chr(37) "  'this returned that  "&" is an invalid character
' " & doc_no " ' || Chr(37) "
' " & doc_no " ' + ""%"" "   returned + as an invalid character
```

I have tried several variations of each type, and I cannot find any similar situation online. Any advice? Again, I am only 4 months into my programming life so bear with me please. Below is a snippet of the code from which the above originates.

```
<%
Dim document(1024)  
counter = 0 
    cmdString = ""
    cmdString = cmdString & "SELECT dbo.dsk_obj.obj_id,"
    cmdString = cmdString & "   docno = dbo.dsk_obj.obj_usr_num "
    cmdString = cmdString & "FROM   dbo.dsk_obj "
    cmdString = cmdString & "WHERE  dbo.dsk_obj.obj_usr_num LIKE '" & doc_no & "'  I NEED TO CONCAT. % HERE "
      objRS.Open    cmdString, objConn, adOpenStatic, 3, adCmdText
       WHILE (objRS.EOF = False) 
       document(counter) = objRS("docno")
       counter = counter + 1
      objRS.MoveNext
        WEND
      objRS.Close
%>

<% FOR ii = 0 TO counter -1 %>
     <%=document(ii)%>
<% 
NEXT
%>
```

the output should look something like this

```
1555307375-0001
1555307375-0002
1555307375-0003
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

First, you should avoid string concatenation because of SQL injection.

Now what you are trying to do is to create a SQL string in VBScript. The SQL you desire looks something like:

```
LIKE '123%'
```

To create this, you need a string in VBScript like:

```
Dim string = "LIKE '123%'"
```

To change out `123` for your doc number, you can do:

```
Dim string = "LIKE '" & doc_no & "123%'"
```

In your case, it would be:

```
cmdString = cmdString & "WHERE  dbo.dsk_obj.obj_usr_num LIKE '" & doc_no & "%'"
```

But please don't do this. You should pass the parameter in instead of using string concatenation.

Comment: Providing a string-concatenation solution when you already recommended avoiding it (for very good reasons) is counter-productive.

Comment: Thank you John, I really appreciate the answer. I will definately pass the parameters in. It is however VERY helpful to me to know how to concatenate, and why to avoid it. Again, thanks for the response, I see now where my syntax error is and know how to correct it :).